# C++ 2D pointer array

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am confused how to allocate "2D array" of pointers.

With some experimenting I have managed to allocate something, which seems to be working, but I have no idea why, so explanation would be great.

This is my whole code:

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


int main() {


int *** ptr = (int ***)malloc(sizeof(int)* 100*100);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    ptr[i] = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int) * 100);
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; ++j)
        ptr[i][j] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 100);
}


cout << *ptr[20][20] << endl;
cout << *ptr[99][20] << endl;


}
```

Ok, they are printing out "garbage values" but it seems good unlike other things I have tried.
So if I am not misteaken this should be equivalent to array[100][100].

My questin is why does each "level" of pointer must have size.

in this line:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 100; ++j)
        ptr[i][j] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 100);
}
```

it looks to me like we are making that each coordinate of 2d array ( I am aware that this is not as same as 2d array ) can hold size of 100 integers, and I only want to save one integer.

but If I remove it like this

```
for (int j = 0; j < 100; ++j)
        ptr[i][j] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
}
```

Then my program stops working. Why ?

Comment: Why are you using malloc in a C++ program? And why are you simply not using vectors?

Comment: Because I come from Java and first thing I heard of is malloc. Is it that bad ?

Comment: "Is it that bad ?"  Yes, and if you come from Java you might also have heard of `new`. You might also want to understand that C++ and Java are almost _completely_ different languages, and that in order to learn C++ you will need a good textbook.

Comment: @gilley if your learning method is hearing of a thing and theń fiddle back and forth some code that use the thing until it appears to work, then I suspect that it will take a long time to learn.

Comment: "C++ and Java are completely different languages, and that in order to learn C++ you will need a good textbook". As far as I understand this can be done this way, maybe it is not good, but it can be done, I have a problem and I am looking for solution. Your answer is not adding any value. Thanks

Comment: "As far as I understand this can be done this way"  No, it can't - your question is a good example of why not. And I made a comment not an answer.

Comment: I accept that vectors are best to use for this. Just for the sake of question, how would u do this in C then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ptr[i] = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int) * 100);
> ```

`ptr[i]` points to a memory block that has room for 100 `int` objects. However, your program tries to cram 100 `int**` objects into that memory block. If `sizeof(int**) > sizeof(int)` and it probably is, then you overflow the allocated memory. The behaviour is undefined.

`sizeof(int)* 100*100` on the other hand is probably way more than is needed for 100 `int***` objects.

---

C++ introduced a feature called new expressions, which implicitly calculate for you the memory required for the allocated object or an array of objects. Use them to avoid bugs like this. They have (almost) made `malloc` obsolete in C++.

Comment: Could you maybe show me proper way to do this ? Basically I want array[100][100] but with pointers. Thank you.

Comment: @gilley this is a 2d array of pointers: `int* array[100][100]`

Comment: @ user2079303 yes it is but it is fixed size, I need it resizable accroding to some other parameters.

Comment: @gilley indeed. Arrays can not be resized. What you need is a "growable array" data structure. However, you do not need to implement it yourself, since the standard library already contains an implementation: `std::vector`

Comment: Thanks for info, I will use vectors instead

Answer (score 0):

I have accepted using vectors is best solution for my problem, but just in case someone needs this in future, this is what I wanted to do:

```
int *** p2 = (int ***)malloc(sizeof(int **)* 100);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
p2[i] = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *)* 100);


for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        p2[i][j] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));

    }
}
```